# A firm farewell - Rest in piece

Tags: riddle, word, three-dimensional, jigsaw-puzzle

[image]

---

> Here is what I believe is the last masterpiece of Avigrail. May God rest his tiny soul.

Comment: You need a hobby. Oh, wait, you have one... and it is *glorious*.  :)   everyone else - click the image, obviously.

Comment: Oh No! Why is this your last masterpiece?

Comment: "wanted to created riddles" - hint or grammatical error?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil According to his profile... it is implied that Avigrail has passed away irl. Not entirely sure though. Would need confirmation.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Well, considering that this puzzle was posted, I find it fairly unlikely that the "passing away" is anything but a story gimmick.

Comment: Does it require the use of a CAD software, given its an STL file?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck He posted on reddit 14 days ago

Comment: Victim of link rot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/366dz0t79m75dai/puzzledColoured.stl

Comment: Time for a hint?

Answer (score 8):

Okay well this is what I have

> There are several coloured pieces. There are four of each colour and they are positioned so from a certain viewpoint they fit together. The viewpoint seems important so here they are:
>
>
> Here's the one for red
>
> [image]
>
>
> And for purple
>
> [image]
>
>
> And for blue (missing tile further back and hidden)
>
> [image]
>
>
> And for pink
>
> [image]

However

> The greens are different. The four pieces don't join up, but make four squares with the greys:
>
>
> 1:
>
> [image]
>
>
> 2:
>
> [image]
>
>
> 3:
>
> [image]
>
>
> 4:
>
> [image]

> To me, red looks very suspicious. Especially how it has rotational symmetry order 4.

Comment: It's also suspicious to me that the entire thing is symmetric. (Or at least, it seems to be.) Maybe something will happen if we somehow color those grey tiles that match with the greens?

Comment: @Deusovi yeah I agree. This must have take a lot of work!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I don't understand the "rotational symmetry of order 4"

Comment: @jaydm26 it means that if you rotated it 360 degrees then it would show the same shape 4 times

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Don't all colours have rotational symmetry? Every coloured square consists of the same piece rotated 90 degrees 4 times.

Comment: @jaydm26 I dont mean the square I mean the entire stucture

Comment: man, these comments read like a very climactic movie trailer.. two people standing in front of a huge mobile-like construction
"did you notice that there is an uncanny symmetry here?" "yeah all those small pieces are symmetrical, so what?"
"no.. i am talking about ..." the camera starts to pan out until the two protagonists are merely ants in front of a huge planetary system.. "the ENTIRE structure!..."